# mysql not seeing data folder

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to mysql, I need to set up a new box with existing DB.

I have a new install of mysql 5.6 on windows.

I have a backup of the data folder of the db I'm interested in (data/abc folder)

I extracted it into the data folder of the new mysql install. Now there is an abc folder under data. However, I can't seem to see the db in mysql to query.

What step am I missing?

Comment: You need to export a .sql file containing the information in the database from the old box and import said .sql file to the new box.

Comment: but I see people using the physical files described in other answers. However, it didn't work for me. I don't have access to the original instance, this is all I can get

Comment: Have you looked at the my.cnf file to see which folder it is pointing to as the datadir?

Comment: it's a clean install, there are no my.cnf in c: or the other usual places

Comment: MySQL starts on my.cnf, so it should be there if you in fact have a running instance of MySQL.I am not sure how to check port status on Windows, but you might want to see what is or is not running on port 3306. In your case you might want to look into MySQL Workbench.